# HTML Gallery to Wordpress Plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress, gallery

I have a HTML gallery I've made. It uses 4 lines of HTML code, 8 lines of jQuery code for  then I choose from some .css files for the effects.
I want to adapt this for Wordpress. I've never made something like this before, so I need some tips: what steps do I need to follow to get this working for Wordpress?

Comment: Check codex docs.. https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good starting point: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

And this will take you through it step by step: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/

Comment: How can I select a CSS file to include?